# Linux Mint 18 installer claims insufficient disk space

Tags: linux-mint, system-installation

I am trying to install Linux Mint 18 Cinnamon alongside Windows 10 on a new Dell XPS 13 laptop. Following a [tutorial](http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2016/04/how-to-install-linux-mint-alongside.html), I shrunk the Windows partition, leaving about 97 GB of unallocated space (GPT partition style) on my hard drive, and I made a Linux Mint USB drive using [Rufus](http://rufus.akeo.ie/). Booting from my 4 GB USB, I chose the option 'Start Linux Mint 18 Cinnamon 64-bit'. Next, I clicked the desktop icon 'Install Linux Mint', selected English as language and then got the following error message:

> You need at least 9.9 GB disk space to install Linux  Mint. This computer has only 4.0 GB.

The installer does not seem to see the internal 97 GB disk space, or is perhaps trying to install Linux Mint on the USB itself? I have seen some forum comments suggesting to change the SATA operation mode, currently this is set to 'RAID On', the other options are 'AHCI' and 'Disabled'. I'm afraid of messing up things, any idea what will help?

Update: Tried with an 8 GB USB stick, the message changed to 'This computer has only 8.0 GB.'

Comment: Before you click icon for installing Linux Mint, open a Terminal und `sudo apt purge dm-raid`  Check with `cat /proc/partitions`  if the new partition have the  expected size.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"RAID On" is bad for Linux: under [Dell XPS 13](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dell_XPS_13_(9350)) the always informed [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dell_XPS_13_(9350)#SATA_controller) says:

> *When the SATA-controller is set to RAID On in Bios, the hard disk (at least the SSD) is not recognized. Set to Off or AHCI (AHCI is recommended) before attempting to install Arch.*

Answer (score 6):

Solution: Switch from RAID to AHCI mode. I was wondering whether this would affect my Windows 10 installation, but following [these instructions](http://www.tenforums.com/drivers-hardware/15006-attn-ssd-owners-enabling-ahci-mode-after-windows-10-installation.html), Windows 10 continued to function properly. After this procedure, booting from USB and running the Linux Mint installer went smoothly. At some point, I was asked whether to unmount partitions in use, which I did, and then I installed Linux Mint alongside Windows. I'm happy with how it worked out - Dell's own [Ubuntu installation instructions](http://www.dell.com/support/article/no/no/nodhs1/SLN151664/en) were helpful too.