# USB boot install Linux not recognizing disk space

Tags: linux-mint, raid

> There seem to be similar questions [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/295365/linux-mint-not-recognising-free-space-created-by-windows-10-shrink?rq=1), [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/283058/linux-mint-17-3-installer-claiming-that-drive-doesnt-have-enough-space?rq=1) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/283058/linux-mint-17-3-installer-claiming-that-drive-doesnt-have-enough-space?noredirect=1&lq=1) but with no confirmed answer, and no answer that addresses my situation satisfactorily.

*Update: I've deleted Windows and reset BIOS factory settings and the problem persists. This is no longer a dual-boot specific question and has been updated.*

I'm trying to install Linux Mint on a Dell XPS 13 9350 with no installed Hard Drive. I also tried Ubuntu with the same results, but I'll talk specifically about Mint in this question as its my desired distro.

I have added Mint to an 8GB USB stick via Yumi. I reboot the machine and hold down <kbd>F12</kbd>, then choose to boot from the USB.

A second screen allows me to "Start" Linux. I start it, and then begin installing from the install icon on the desktop. After being asked about language, keyboard and WiFi I'm told that I only have 10GB of space, which is not enough to install. It appears to be trying to install on the USB drive, as this is a 256GB hard drive.

Output of `lsblk -f`:

```
NAME        FSTYPE   LABEL                          UUID                      MOUNTPOINT
loop0       iso966   Linux Mint 19 Cinnamon 64-bit  2018-06-26-15-38-36-00    /cdrom
loop1       squashfs                                                          /rofs
sda                                                                        
Ｌsda1      vfat     MULTIBOOT                      190...                    /isodevice
nvme0n1
Ｌnvme0n1p1 ext4                                    16639...
```

I have manually toggled "RAID On" to AHCI in the BIOS and that allowed me to complete the Linux install wizard, but gave me a Dell Support window message on boot about a missing OS. Since then I have reset to factory BIOS settings and I get a "Missing Hard Drive" message on boot.

What can I do to both install and boot up Mint, now on a computer with no OS?

Comment: @dsstorefile1 I have. None of my volumes are dynamic though. I added that to my answer

Comment: There's an answered question here that applies to some Dell XPS 13: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/328687/linux-mint-18-installer-claims-insufficient-disk-space?rq=1

Comment: @sourcejedi I saw that. I just set it from RAID On to AHCI and while it allows me to install Linux, now the computer won't boot up except from the USB drive. It says it can't find an OS. Not sure if this is answers the question.

Comment: @sourcejedi neither. I changed to AHCI and installed Mint and erased Windows. So I seem to have gotten myself into a new problem, which may require a new question if I can't get myself out.

Comment: @steel gah, sorry for not reading properly. On some systems that might show your OS needs you to disable Secure Boot in the BIOS. I don't have anything telling me that's true in your case, it's just one of those things people will suggest to see if it works :).

Comment: @sourcejedi secure boot is disabled :(

Comment: Please add the output of `lsblk -f` so we can see the drives and partitions you're working with. The screenshot you mentioned in an earlier comment is missing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to solve this with the help of a colleague, finally. It took several steps in BIOS:

1. Disable Secure Boot.
2. Set SATA-controller to AHCI from RAID On.
3. Set boot mode to legacy from UEFI.

I wasn't able to figure out exactly what was wrong, but the installer seems to have installed the OS in a drive that UEFI did not auto-detect, but legacy boot mode did.

Comment: this last answer by steel worked for me too, even without the option #3 (I'm working with a Dell XPS 13 (7390) and it does not support anymore Legacy mode on boot.

Comment: Thank you for confirming #2 for me. Please note, you do not need to necessarily modify to legacy from UEFI. But Disabling Secure Boot will find the flash drive, Setting "RAID On" to AHCI will make the partitions/drive detectable.

Answer (score 2):

Your bootloader/EFI partition is on `/dev/sda` while the computer is most likely looking for it on `/dev/nvme0`.
(I have had a laptop that was hard-coded to boot from the internal SSD before)

You need to move or create it onto the `nvme` device to get it to boot properly.

A reinstallation, where you select manual partitioning, would be the easiest way.

[This article](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/EFI_System_Partition) has information on how the EFI partition should be for it to work properly.

Comment: sda looks like the live-USB actually. It would be possible to boot with just a single partition, but of course that implies not using EFI, which is a bit odd.

Comment: @mioriin, A reinstallation of what? My issue is that I have no OS and cannot install from the USB.

Answer (score 1):

#### Idea #1

According to the ArchLinux Wiki with respect to this [laptop (Dell XPS 13 (9350))](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dell_XPS_13_(9350)):

> When the SATA-controller is set to RAID On in Bios, the hard disk (at least the SSD) is not recognized. Set to Off or AHCI (AHCI is recommended) before attempting to install Arch.

#### Idea #2

In the section below that, NVM Express SSD, there's guidances on how to get the SSD to be detected properly during boot/installation:

> The location of the nvme module for "NVM Express" SSD has changed between linux kernel version 4.3 and 4.4. If you experience "cannot find root device" on boot, it may be due to the nvme module not being present in initramfs. In this case, the following may resolve your issue.
>
> Edit your `/etc/mkinitcpio.conf` file:
>
> ```
>   ...
>    MODULES=(... "nvme")
>    ...
> ```
>
> Then update the bootloader.
>
> ```
>   # mkinitcpio -p linux
> ```
>
> where linux is the name of the image loaded on boot. If you installed linux-mainlineAUR then change that to linux-mainline.

#### Idea #3

There's also this thread, titled: [Grub and NVMe device](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=209653) that discusses a booting issue with this laptop, GRUB, and NVMe HDD's.

> However, trying to boot using the freshly installed grub instance, I get the error "no such device: "
>   I've checked, the UUIDs, the one given in the error message matches the UUID of /boot, so the configuration of the boot partition at least is as expe

The workaround is mentioned in that same thread, basically use a different boot loader.

#### References

- [Youtube video discussing the GRUB boot issue](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kvsgTJbIWNo&feature=youtu.be&t=229)

Comment: Thanks for the response. In my question I noted that I toggled RAID off and AHCI on with consequences. Maybe you could explain what that looks like to do correctly? That is part of the requirement stated for the bounty.

Comment: I have no access to this particular type of laptop so cannot really show exact steps. I saw the requirement, was looking through backlog of Q's was trying to provide assistance. Did you try a different distro to see if it was just Mint's particulars?

Comment: I tried Ubuntu with the same results.

Comment: @steel https://certification.ubuntu.com/hardware/201508-18805/ shows that you need the latest firmware but this h/w should be supported.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/731931/uefi-not-finding-a-bootable-system-on-xps13

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/961701/installed-ubuntu-16-04-on-dell-erasing-windows-10-no-booting-device-found

Comment: Okay, I think I've parsed through all of your information now. Nothing is resolving the issue, but here's a summary: Disabling RAID allows me to install but boots up with "No bootable devices found"; I do not have a /efi directory; I do not have a /etc/mkinitcpio.conf file; I do not see the error "no such device".

Comment: @steel - my suspicion is that you need to be using the efi and when you deleted the Windows partition(s) you deleted the bootloader that was there. Do you have any method that gets back a usable Windows scenario?

Comment: I have no way to re-install Windows for now. I'll have to figure out whether to spend money on that or on someone to fix this for me. Is there an efi directory somewhere other than "/"?

Comment: @steel - I believe you have to create it.