# Dual Boot Windows 10 / Linux Mint 19.3 on Dell XPS 13 (7390)

Tags: linux-mint, windows, dual-boot, raid

As I'm new to dual boot Linux with Windows I'm probably missing a lot during this process and I'll be glad if someone can help me sort things out.

I got a new Dell XPS 13 (7390). It came with Windows 10 Home installed, which I need to maintain for work reasons, but I'd like to have Linux Mint as my primary OS.

I followed Dell's instructions to install Linux by shrinking the Windows' partition and then using that creating 4 new partitions in it: /boot; /root; /home; /swap.

Please do tell me if you need to know more about my machine to understand what's happening.

At first I had problems in make my USB flash drive recognize the unallocated space, which I finally solved as explained [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/462070) (but without setting boot mode to legacy (as it is no longer possible).

Now I have the two systems installed. The only problem is that I can boot Windows only selecting "Raid On" on BIOS settings, while Mint works only switching it back to AHCI mode.

Is there a way to solve this and not touch the BIOS every time?

Comment: Is this helpful? https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-hardware/how-to-enable-ahci-for-ssd-in-windows-10/18ee0b43-47a9-4344-b0c8-1e8546be2c82

Comment: FYI, a dedicated swap partition in Linux has been passe since fall of '17. Then. the kernel issue which slowed swap file access was fixed. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq for swap file sizing tips.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this re-installing Windows on AHCI mode. Now the Grub screen can easily bring me to Mint or Windows without problems and without having to touch the BIOS everytime.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it is possible to migrate a Windows installation from RAID to AHCI, rather than having to reinstall Windows completely on AHCI mode. Windows will do this migration automatically if you can just get it to boot in AHCI using safe mode.

To do this, while the BIOS is still in RAID mode, use Win+R to bring up the run prompt and type msconfig.exe. In the Boot tab, enable Safe boot + Minimal and Apply.

Now reboot and change the BIOS to AHCI mode. Reboot again: Windows should successfully boot in safe mode, meaning the migration is complete. You should be back in business on your next boot.

Reference:
https://gist.github.com/chenxiaolong/4beec93c464639a19ad82eeccc828c63